# assertTrue/assertFalse if statements

Tags: java, jna

How can you use assertTrue and assertFalse in if statements? Just throwing in if statement in front does not work, gives me a syntax error, but it was worth a shot. I tried to make it a string and check value with value.equals() but assert gives an error saying you cannot convert to a string.

```
public class JNAWinRegTest extends TestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

    try { assertEquals("Windows 7 Professional", Advapi32Util.registryGetStringValue(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
            "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", "ProductName"));
        if(True) ){
            System.out.println("True");
        }else{
            if(False) ){
                System.out.println("False");    
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                                              
        }  
    }
```

Comment: All `assert...()` methods have return type `void`, so they can't be used in `if` statements.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just call `assertEquals(expected, actual)` - if `expected.equals(actual)`, the test continues to the next line (and pass when it reaches the last line), if the condition is false, the test fails.

No need for additional if / else.

Comment: Yes. And when it fails, it throws AssertionFailedError according to this javadoc http://www.junit.org/junit/javadoc/3.8.1/junit/framework/Assert.html (I assumed you are using junit3's TestCase)

Comment: the reason for the if statement will be to run commands depending on the answer. like to run this fix for win 7 or that fix for win xp. Maybe I should be using something else... ?

Comment: the statements after your `assertEquals` will only be executed if the condition you test in `assertEquals` is true. If it isn't, `assertEquals` will throw an exception.

Comment: What do you mean: *"like to run this fix for win 7 or that fix for win xp"*? The code you show is a unit test, not a production code, right?

Comment: It is not a production code, just some tests for now. At somepoint it will be a production code once I know that it will work. I have never used assert before, just saw an example of it.

Comment: assertEquals sould only be used in tests. If you need to act based on the result, you should use a standard `if(a.equals(b)) { doSomething();} else {doSomethingElse();}` construct.